# How to create multiple WAR files from single pom.xml?

Tags: maven

I am having single build.xml, Which is creating multiple WAR files for my project. I am doing migration from Ant build to maven build. How to create multiple WAR files from single pom.xml?

Comment: Use maven assembly plugin see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882322/how-do-i-get-maven-2-to-build-2-separate-war-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest to build a multi module maven project, where each war is the output of a single module.
Look at the [mini guide for multiple modules](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) and this [multimodule reference](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html) for more details.

I hope this helps.

Comment: But I want to create multiple WAR files for a single project. In my ant script Each WAR is created using different resource of the same project. And I want to do the same, by using Single pom.xml? Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can do it as suggested by @Vinay Lodha, but it's not the maven way. Learn maven and use it as intended and don't warp it...

Answer (score -1):

You can use build different [maven profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) to build each wars

Comment: It could be an alternative, but then you have to build for each profile, is there a possibility that you do mvn build once and it do for all the profiles ?