# How to create multiple assemblies by single pom.xml

Tags: maven, build, automation, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I want to create multiple assemblies using maven , for each directory without going for multi module.
my project structure looks like this

```
├───assembly
├───src
│   └───main
│       └───environments
│           ├───dev
│           │   └───some files
│           └───local
│           │    └───some file
│           └───test
│               └───some files
└───target
|   ├───dev.zip
|   └───local.zip
|   ├───test.zip
│           
│           
│           
│              
└───pom.xml
```

As in above project structure i want to build three zip files for directories dev, local and test

A similar question i found [How to create multiple WAR files from single pom.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23241985/how-to-create-multiple-war-files-from-single-pom-xml). But i am looking for a solution without going multi modules.

Comment: What is the problem with going multi module?

Comment: With multi modules, the same pom files and assembly file will be repeated with little change, also then every module will generate the assembly zip file in its own target directory. I want to avoid these two things